# Best Practices Of Referencing Custom Library Assemblies in a Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assemblies, gac, solution

In our company we have got a custom library. We are using it in most of projects and our library is still developing. So sometimes we had to build and generate new assemblies twice or more in a day.

We were using GAC to store our custom libraries assemblies. As you guess replacing GAC with new assemblies become boring.

For this reason we decided to create a folder in solution that name is Referenced Assemblies and created a Solution Items folder and added assemblies this solution folder. So when we Get Latest from TFS we can get new versions of assemblies. This is more easier than GAC (but in theoratically)

When we started to use; problems became clear. For example sometimes Visual Studio marks DLL "delete,lock", despite not delete. Or sometimes when our team members open a form, designer throws exception because of could not find releated classes in assemblies. We had to rebuild solution or restart Visual Studio for several times.

Storing assemblies in GAC or Referenced Assemblies folder has a common problem. You need to put new assemblies somewhere to share other team members. For example, if assemblies stored in GAC, they can share via UNC, else if assemblies stored in Referenced Assemblies folder, new assemblies had been copied to other projects which required.

What is the best practices for storing referenced assemblies in a solution?

We ara using VS 2010 and TFS 2010. 
Our projects framework version is 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NuGet / NuPack](http://nupack.codeplex.com/)

- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingNuPackPackageManagementforNETAnotherpieceoftheWebStack.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/06/announcing-nupack-asp-net-mvc-3-beta-and-webmatrix-beta-2.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but i saw that it works with only well known libraries or open source projects. We don't use any projects like this. Can we use this with our custom libraries?

Comment: I looked NuGet deeply and decided to use in future. Because i am waiting that NuGet can download package contents from an UNC share or web. so is there any alternatives?